# Draw  Dynamic Shapes

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, shapes

I need some help to make an activity.

I have stored coordinates from shapes and name of shapes in a database. These are grouped into rooms.
In the activity I need the top of the screen 8 TextViews (with colors and textst) in two rows. If I click on a textView, accordingly the shapes for the room need to be drawn on the screen under the textViews.

If I click on a shape, I need to get back the information, on which shape I made a click.

Comment: So what do you need help with? Where have you gotten so far? We can't help you if you don't tell us how can we help you.

Comment: Im a beginner, so i dont gotten far. 1. I need to know the layout for the textviw part and for the drawing part. 2. I need to know how to draw multiple shapes in the drawing part 3. how to reset and redraw this part 4. how i can get exactly, which shape was clicked

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could create a custom view:

```
public class CustomView extends View { ... }
```

and then you simply override appropriate methods like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) { /* check for hitting shapes here */ }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { /* draw anything you want here */ }
```

Use the search engine of your choice to find out more. [This looks like what you need](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/08/creatingcustomviews/)

Comment: Just as an fyi, your link appears to be dead. Domain is listed for sale.